# How to change a simple xml hierarchy with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following source xml:

```
<to id="abc">
   <ti></ti>
   <b>
   ...
       <to id="bcd"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
       <to id="cde"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
       <to id="def"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
   </b>
</to>
```

The "..." means a lot of bodydiv li and nodetext in between.

I want to transform it to:

```
<to id="abc">
    <ti></ti>
    <b>
     ...
    </b>
    <to id="bcd"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
    <to id="cde"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
    <to id="def"><ti></ti><b>...</b></to>
 </to>
```

What is the most easy way to express the transformation in xslt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're only moving `to` outside of `b`. Not sure why you would need to base anything on `@id`.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::to)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="to"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do, it uses the identity transformation template to copy everything and adds two templates, the first to handle the `to[@id = 'abc']` element and the second to handle its `b` child element:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="to[@id = 'abc']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | b/to[@id]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="to[@id = 'abc']/b">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::to[@id])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this acurate, fast answer. Now I understand much more of this kind of XSLT'ing. I changed "to[@id = 'abc']" into "to[@id = /to/@id]" so I get the right result also if the id from the toplevel "to"-element equal it was autogenerated.